# Installing Xdebug 3 to debug PHP code inside a Docker container

Tags: php, docker, centos7, xdebug, pecl

I need to enable the possibility to debug my PHP code inside a Docker.

The idea is to install Xdebug 3 in the PHP container.

Please note that I've built the Docker image starting from CentoOS 7 where I installed PHP 8.1 (for certian reasons I have to use `CentoOS7` + `php8.1`)

I'm trying to run this command into the Dockerfile in order to install the component:

```
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

I'm receiving an error because pecl seems not installed.
**How can install pecl into the my image (CentoOS 7) with HP 8.1?**

Please note that I installed these PHP modules:

```
RUN rpm -ivh https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm && \
    yum -y install \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-dev \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-ast \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-bcmath \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-cli \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-common \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-devel \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-fpm \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-FFI \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-gd \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-imap \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-intl \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-json \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-ldap \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-mbstring \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-mysqlnd \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-opcache \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pdo \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pear \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pecl-apcu \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pecl-apm \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pecl-crypto \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pecl-event \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pecl-igbinary \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pecl-inotify \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pecl-lzf \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pecl-mcrypt \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pecl-msgpack \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pecl-mysql \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pecl-oauth \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pecl-redis5 \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pecl-zip \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-process \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-soap \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-xml \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-runtime \
    php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-sodium
```

Comment: You don't need to use the pecl command, add "php${PHP_INSTALL_VERSION}-php-pecl-xdebug3" to the list of installed packages

Comment: Is not necessary this docker-php-ext-enable xdebug?

Comment: no, once installed from RPM, extension are enabled.